# Beginner question about CPU clock

Tags: avr, atmel

So I just started learning AVR and I am currently working with the ATMega328P. I have a question regarding the CPU clock. Currently I am using the 8MHz internal clock. Now I know that F_CPU tells the compiler what my clock speed is. The problem here is that the CLKDIV8 fuse is programmed by default, so I was wondering what value would I enter for F_CPU? Will it be 8000000 or 1000000.

I would be glad if someone could clear this confusion.

Comment: https://www.kanda.com/blog/microcontrollers/avr-microcontrollers/avr-microcontroller-default-clock/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1Mhz, until/unless you change the CLKDIV8 fuse, then it's 8MHz